# $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $r>0$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $n - r < -b < n + r$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose I've got a real number $b \in \mathbb{R}$ which obeys the property:

For every $r>0$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n - r < -b < n + r $.

(equivalent to: for every $r>0$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n+b|<r$, I think)

Is it true that $b=-n$? How can I formally prove this? This looks suspiciously like the definition of a limit, but I'm not entirely convinced.

EDIT: I was wrong, it forces $ (-b) \in \mathbb{N} $. But how can I prove this?

Comment: I think that this property is equivalent to $-b\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: If you replaced $\Bbb N$ with $\Bbb Q$, it would be equivalent to $-b\in\Bbb R$ (or $b\in\Bbb R$). Basically, $-b$ is in the closure of the set.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right - it forces $(-b) \in \mathbb{N}$. How can this be proven using the above informaiton though?

Comment: Question: What's your definition of $\Bbb N$? Is it $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$? Different books use different definitions.

Comment: Also, your initial version asked something else. Before you edited, the answer _was_ $b=-n$, I believe.

Comment: The definition I'm using is $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, .....\}$. And sorry about that, I made a mistake in writing it out. I should have added another edit comment.

Comment: Hint: Let $d$ be the distance between $-b$ and the natural number nearest to it. If $-b$ isn't a natural number, we'd have $d>0$…

Comment: Great. So I define $r_{0} = \min\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\{|(-b)-m|\}$. Since the distance function is positive-definite, this minimum must exist. If $(-b)\notin \mathbb{N}$ we get $r_{0}>0$. Then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n-r_{0}<(-b)<n+r_{0}$ (I'm assuming that I must be getting a contradiction out of this).

Comment: Pick $r>0$ satisfying $r<r_{0}$. Then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n-(-b)|<r<r_{0}$. But there can exist no such $n \in \mathbb{N}$ from our definition of $r_{0}$? Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that $b < 0$, as $r = \frac{1}{2}$ shows that $0 < n - \frac{1}{2} < -b$

Suppose $b = -k + \epsilon$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 < \epsilon < 1$, and take $0 < r < \min(1-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Then, if $n - r < -b$, we have that $n < -b + r = k - (\epsilon - r) < k$. If $-b < n + r$, we have that $n > -b -r = k  - (r + \epsilon) > k - 1$. So $k - 1 < n < k$, where $k$ and $n$ are natural numbers, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we must have had $\epsilon = 0$, and $b = -k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.